# Best way to stock 2xx millions of points

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers

So I need to have an array of Terrain (ground) which contains 2xx little terrain (ground). Each little terrain(ground) contains 1 000 000 floats points.

So I thought about something like

```
QVector<QVector<float> > terrain;
QVector<float> littleTerrain;
```

But at a moment there is a problem with all the allocations I can do .

So of course, I thought about

```
QVector<float*>
```

but it's necessary to delete all the pointers in the vector

So, using the smart pointer is possible here ? Otherwise, what is the best choice to do ?

Comment: what is 2xx? I'm not familiar with the notation

Comment: "But at a moment there is a problem with all the allocations I can do ." That does mean what exactly? @fritzone: Between 200 and 300 million

Comment: you mean `QVector<QVector<float>*>` ?

Comment: When it come closer to 170 millions, it seems I can't go further ( it warning me that I need to close others applications to continue .. )
@FredrickGauss no I used QVector<QVector<float> > terrain;

Comment: Container operations in the `stl` use copy ctors often. Since your vector has `1m` floats, and each upper terrain vector has 200(i assume 2xx is 200 here) vector of these vectors, each ground vector has 2x10^8x4 bytes : ~ 762MB (actually more than that). If there is more than one ground there, adding/moving/assigning/deleting will hit for a performance deficit.

Answer (score 0):

float is 4 bytes and pointer is also 4 bytes in 32bit config so there is no point to hold pointers for your floats. Vectors can be used for you purpose but you should first reserve memory for your vectors. Also try to determined the limits of your vector implementation. Implementation can be different from library to library.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to support 64 bit architectures, then certainly a list of vectors would work. It'll work very crappily since there's likely not enough physical RAM to back it all up.

On 32 bit architectures you don't have enough address space to keep it all in a simple data structure anyway.

So, what you need to do is a caching scheme where only a subset of this data is resident in the in-memory data structure at any time. To optimize the caching behavior, at all levels (L1, L2, L3, paging), you need to - and this is important -- **keep spatially neighboring data in neighboring memory addresses**.

One way of doing it would be to have all terrain subdivided into 32x32 unit squares. Note that  `32*32*sizeof(float) == 4096` is the small page size on most systems. This square should be further subdivided in 4x4 unit squares. Note that `4*4*sizeof(float) == 64` and is the cache line size on many systems.

Comment: Don't know about your computer, but 200 lists of vectors have an overhead measured in kilobytes. No problem at all, not even in 16 bits. The individual vectors take 4 MB each, which is small enough to not run into major fragmentation issues even on 32 bit systems.

Comment: @MSalters 300 * 1 million * 4 = 1.2GB, out of 2GB available under 32 bit Windows. Way too close to be practical, especially with growth potential. Even if that much virtual address space is available, it may not be all available in 4MB chunks. It's not about fragmentation, it's about locality of access. Accessing a 1000x1 vertical strip in one of those 4MB chunks requires paging in the entire chunk just to access 4kBytes worth of data, and will waste 1000 cache lines too - nuts.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead will be proportional to the number of containers you have - a few hundred containers, a few kilobytes in total. Nothing at all, in other words.

The important thing to do is to reserve sufficient memory for the number of points per "littleTerrain". Otherwise Qt will make sure it fits, but probably overallocate by 50% or so.